# Pandas - replace categorical text with numpy arrays for machine learning

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a file:

```
data = pd.read('data.csv')
```

And that file contains categorical text data about digital users such as: (source = 'google', 'facebook', 'twitter') and (country = 'US', 'FR', 'GER').

Using the `sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer()` class, I've managed to turn these categories into numpy arrays. I then created a dictionary, which contains the text categories as keys, and the vectorized numpy arrays for the relevant category as the value, i.e.:

```
{'google': np.array([0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])}
{'facebook': np.array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])}
{'FR': np.array([0., 0., 1.])}
```

What I would ideally like to do is replace each text category (e.g., 'google') with it's vectorized numpy array value (e.g., `np.array([0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]`), so that I can then use a feature reduction algorithm to reduce the features down to 2, for visualization purposes.

So ideally, a row in the data that reads:

```
source | country 
google | FR
twitter| US
```

Would read:

```
source                             | country
np.array([0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]) | np.array([0., 0., 1.])
np.array([1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]) | np.array([1., 0., 0.])
```

Could someone recommend the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a little bit more succinct operation for converting the categorical to a numerical representation. I had to brush up on it a little since I've been using R mostly lately. [This blog post](http://fastml.com/converting-categorical-data-into-numbers-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/) was a great resource.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

d = {'source' : pd.Series(['google', 'facebook', 'twitter','twitter'],
                          index=['1', '2', '3', '4']),
     'country' : pd.Series(['GER', 'GER', 'US', 'FR'], 
                           index=['1', '2', '3', '4'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_as_dicts=df.T.to_dict().values()
```

The `df.T` gives the transpose that we then apply the `to_dict()` to get the list of dictionaries that DictVectorizer wants. The `values()` method returns just the values, we don't want the indices.

df_as_dicts:

```
 [{'source': 'google', 'country': 'GER'},
 {'source': 'twitter', 'country': 'US'},
 {'source': 'facebook', 'country': 'GER'},
 {'source': 'twitter', 'country': 'FR'}]
```

Then the conversion using DictVectorizer follows:

```
vectorizer = DictVectorizer( sparse = False )
d_as_vecs = vectorizer.fit_transform( df_as_dicts )
```

resulting in:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

`get_feature_names()` allows us to retrieve the column names for this array from the vectorizer if we want to check our result.

```
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['source=facebook',
 'source=google',
 'source=twitter',
 'country=FR',
 'country=GER',
 'country=US']
```

We can confirm the conversion has given us a correct representation of the test data in one-hot encoding form.

Comment: great answer @Seth_P

Answer (score 0):

So I found 'a' solution to my problem, maybe not 'the' solution. I went back and made new dictionaries of my key, value pairs:

Create lists to store keys, values in:

```
keys = []
values = []
```

Add keys and values to lists:

```
for column in category_columns:
    keys.append(data[column].unique().tolist())
for matrix in vectorized_data:
    values.append(matrix)
```

Result (continuing with my above examples):

```
keys = ['google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
values = [np.array([0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]), np.array([1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), np.array([0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])]
```

Create a list of dictionaries with keys, values:

```
unique_vect = []
for i in range(0, len(keys)):
    unique_vect.append(dict(zip(keys[i], values[i])))
```

Then I used pandas' `.map()` function to replace the existing values with the numpy arrays I created from the `DictVectorizer`

```
data['affiliate_channel'] = data['affiliate_channel'].map(unique_vect[0].get)
```

And I repeated this step for each column.

It's amazing what a little brain power, and a few hours of Google can do. If anyone can think of a better/quicker/more Pythonic way to do this, I'd appreciate it.